# Creation of a new component

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

If I make a component and register it, then later want to change the properties of that component.
Do I have to re-register it as a new component or can I edit the current component?

Comment: 1. You don't have to reinstall the component if you make changes only to its runtime part (it means no change in its published section), so the IDE doesn't need to reflect those changes. 2. It's the best candidate if you don't want to have a focusable control. If you want your component be able to get a focus and be controllable by keyboard, use `TCustomControl` instead.

Comment: As TLama said .. 1 you dont need to reRegister your component . 2 i think that you should inherit your component from TGraphiControl (Only if you dont need a Handle to your component ).

Comment: What does *change the property's* mean? Presumably the apostrophe is a  typo and you meant to write properties. If so are you asking what you do when you change the name and/or type of a property? Who uses the component? Just you, or are there other developers using it. Be more precise.

Comment: Just me. Also maybe better question is at what point would I have to reinstall the componet? By change I mean add new properties to change name of one of functions  or add new functions. Or change property type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **it depends**

**Reinstall required for design time changes**
If you make changes to the published properties of a component, they will not show during **design** time unless you uninstall and reinstall it.

This is because Delphi keeps the component in a BPL file, which is binary.

**No reinstall needed if...**
If the changes only affect the **run** time behavior, then you don't need to reinstall the component, because Delphi will pickup the source code.

**But the component source needs to be visible in your project code**
However for this last option to be true, the source code of the component needs to be in the search path of your project, otherwise it will still pick up the data from the .bpl file.

Reinstalling a component is easy in XE2 though.
Step 1: open the .dpk file your component is in
Step 2: make changes to the .pas file of your component
Step 3: Install
[image]

If you choose install, Delphi will automatically reinstall your component.
If compilation is unsuccessful your old version will stay installed.

**Note**
You don't register a **new** component, you change the source code of the currently registered (`installed` is the current lingo) component and re-install it by choosing <kbd>install</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't need to re-register it.
All you'll have to do is recompile the package where the component is in.